# user story developers view

Tags: agile, scrum, user-stories

We have a set of user stories, and all the stories got confirmed with stockholders, then we assigned this user story to our development team,

Question:

1. How the user story document helps to developers? Because it’s not in detail level like validation and business rule
2. User card contain acceptance criteria only, this is also not help to developers

Let me know how we can approach to developers (in terms of requirement) with user story? Or want to create any other specific template or want to create a detail requirement document from the user story?

Comment: This question belongs on [Project Management](http://pm.stackexchange.com/), it is off-topic for Stack Overflow because it is not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming. Project management is off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 1):

A user story is kept deliberately vague. The reason for this is it is an 'invitation to a conversation'. In Scrum the Product Owner explains each user story to the team at the sprint planning and backlog refinement meetings.

There are a few reasons why this approach is used:

- We want to encourage conversation rather than written requirements
- We want the details to be added at the latest possible time, so that we are able to quickly adapt to changes in requirements

This does not mean the developers only have to work with the original user story. They will often update the story with acceptance criteria and other details during the discussion with the Product Owner. They will add *just enough* detail to the user story to allow them to complete the work.